# Reply to email using imap email object

Tags: python, email, smtp

I have an email object of an unread email. How do I reply to the email using SMTP lib using the specific email object i.e. (if mail comes from flipkart, the particular mail has an object. I want to reply using that mail object)? I tried using `msg['Reply_To']`  and I got an error saying the email id is not valid. I did check the smtp documentation and couldn't find anything regarding the same. Here when I comment the [send to] and only add [reply to] the error is shown below. But when I uncomment the same the mail is sent but it is not sent as a reply. This shows that the email id is correct.

CODE:

```
    def SendReply(self):
        self.msg["from"] = self.From
        self.msg["Cc"] = self.cc
        self.msg["To"] = self.To
        self.msg["Subject"] = self.Subject
        self.Body = str(self.Body)
        self.msg["Reply_To"] = self.Reply_To
        self.msg.set_content(self.Body)
        # print("Print this now", self.msg["Reply_To"])

        if self.Attachments is not None:
            with open(self.Attachments, "rb") as f:
                file_data = f.read()
                self.msg.add_attachment(
                    file_data,
                    maintype="application",
                    subtype="xlsx",
                    filename=self.Attachments,
                )

        with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as smtp:
            smtp.starttls()
            smtp.login(self.From, self.EmailPassword)
            self.msg["Reply_To"] = self.Reply_To
            smtp.send_message(self.msg)
        return ("Mail sent Succesfully", True)
```

ERROR:

```
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: 
   {'None': (553, 
    b'5.1.3 The recipient address <None> is not a valid RFC-5321 address. 
    Learn\n5.1.3 more at\n5.1.3  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 ij25-20020a170902ab5900b0016beceac426sm3191763plb.138 - gsmtp')}
```

Comment: as I know it doesn't have special function to reply. You have to read mail, get information from this mail and use it to create new mail with response.

Comment: error shows that you used `None` as recipient address. We can't see your code, and we can't read in your mind - so we have no idea what you are doing, and we can't help you.

Comment: what did you assign to `msg['to']` - sometimes spamers can send message without own address and you can't copy it into response. maybe you should first use `print()` to see what you get in variables. And you could use `if/else` to send response only if you have address

Comment: I'll add the code for your reference @furas

Comment: @furas, from my understanding the email id is correct as when I'm giving ['To'] the email is sent correctly.

Comment: you have `self.msg["Reply_To"] = self.Reply_To` - maybe check what you have in `self.Reply_To`. Maybe it is `None`. If you use code `self.Reply_To = variable` then use `print(variable)` to see what you have in this variable, etc.

Comment: I did check that and it prints the email address.

Comment: Could you add a small snippet of code that is used to reply to an email thread?

Comment: first check what you have in variables - especially in `To` - because it seems you have `None` in this variable. And if you want to send reply to received mail `msg` then you should rather use `msg["To"] = self.From` or `msg["To"] = self.Reply_To` (if `Reply_To` is not `None` - because some emails may not send `Reply_To`)

Comment: I don't know if I understand you but `Reply_To` is not user's address but your address which user's program wiill use to send message back to you. Often `Reply_To` is the same as `From`. But some times it may be something like `From = "you@your_domain.com` and `Reply_To = office@your_domain.com` - so smtp will send this mail using `you@` but when user will try to reply the useer will send to `office@`

Comment: I tested `smtp` and I get your error message `smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'None': (553, ...` only when I set `msg['To'] = None`

Comment: From my understanding ['Reply To'] is used to reply to an email. So, should we give the email id of the mail to which we are replying? I got an email from 'a@gmail.com' and had given 'a@gmail.com' as the email address in ['reply to']. I tried giving ['To'] = a@gmail.com and ['Reply_To'] = a@gmail.com in the program. The email was sent to 'a@gmail.com' but was not a reply email. When I tried using only ['Reply-To'] = 'a@gmail.com' it gave me the error you were highlighting.

Comment: `reply` in NOT to reply for this email - it is information for user's mail program where to send his reply when he press `Reply` in his mail program. IF you don't set `reply` then when user press press `Reply` in his mail program then will send reply to `from` address

Comment: it seems you expect `msg["In-Reply-To"] = original_message_ID`. And if you want to see original message's content in your mail then you may have to add this on your own in `body` because `smtplib` will not add it automatically

Comment: Could you please add an example snippet code on the same?